# Can't seem to print string array(agents.cpp) from the main using a call to a for loop within the agents class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print the array to screen. Unfortunately, it prints 4 blank lines instead.

```
// CarWarhouse.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "agents.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string agentName;
    int agentID;

    agents A_1;

    cout << "Administrative login: ";
    cin >> agentName;
    A_1.setAgentName(agentName);
    cout << "Administrative password: ";
    cin >> agentID;

    while (agentID != A_1.getAgentID())
    {
        cout << "Invalid login\n";

        cout << "\nAdministrative password: ";
        cin >> agentID;
    }

    cout << endl << "Welcome back, Agent " << endl;

    cout << "Active Agents: " << endl;

    A_1.agentIdentities(); //Function call to agents.cpp

}

agents.cpp

#include "pch.h"
#include "agents.h"
#include <string>

agents::agents() {
    agentName = "";
    agentID = 1111;
    int const size = 4;
    string agentMembers[size] = { "Jacob", "Nathan", "Tomas", "Jack" }; //Agent members string array I want to print to screen.
}

agents::agents(string name, int ID)
{
    agentName = name;
    agentID = ID;
}

agents::~agents()
{}


string agents::getAgentName() const
{
    return  agentName;
}

int agents::getAgentID() const
{
    return agentID;
}

void agents::setAgentName(string incoming)
{
    agentName = incoming;
}

void agents::setAgentIdentity(int ID)
{
    agentID = ID;
}

void agents::agentIdentities() //Main calls this function.
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << agentMembers[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << agentMembers[0];
}


#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef agents_h
#define agents_h

class agents{

public:
    //First thing, default constructor
    agents();

    //Overload Constructor
    agents(string, int);

    //Destructor

    ~agents();

    //Accessor Functions

    //If accessor doesn't modify member variables, end with const on the function name.

    string getAgentName() const;
        //getName returns name of the customer.

    int getAgentID() const;


    void setAgentName(string);
    //getName returns the newly assigned customer reference number.

    void setAgentIdentity(int);

    void agentIdentities();
    //Retrieves agent identites (names within the string array).

private:
    //Member variables
    string agentName;
    int agentID;
    string agentMembers[4];
    int size = 4;
};

#endif
```

I've identified within the code the three areas of key interest. I've trying to print a string array from the main using a function call from the main to agents.cpp.

Each time I run this code, it prints 4 blank lines, I'm fairly new to c++ in the sense that it's my starting 4 weeks at University.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a close look at your `agents` constructor. What are you doing with the ***local*** variable `size` and `agentMembers`? How would those be related to the *member* variables with the same name?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific if possible? I'm four weeks into this so my knowledge isn't expansive at all.

Comment: Then please go back to your tutorial or book or class-notes where it goes through variables, scopes and life-time. If you define two variables with the same name but in different scopes (that might be nested) then those are two different variables without any relationship.

Comment: Well, that was pretty passive-aggressive; Telling me to go back to my tutor doesn't really offer any constructive insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the error (very common newbie error)

```
agents::agents() {
    agentName = "";
    agentID = 1111;
    int const size = 4;
    string agentMembers[size] = { "Jacob", "Nathan", "Tomas", "Jack" }; 
}
```

it should be

```
agents::agents() {
    agentName = "";
    agentID = 1111;
    size = 4;
    agentMembers = { "Jacob", "Nathan", "Tomas", "Jack" }; 
}
```

Your code declares *new variables* called `size` and `agentMembers` that are completely unrelated to the variables declared in your class (apart from having the same name). That's why your constructor doesn't update the class variables because all you are setting are some local variables which no longer exist once the constructor has been exitted.

However since we're on the topc of constructors it's worth pointing out that the best way to initialise class variables is to use an initialiser list

```
agents::agents() : agentName(""), agentID(1111), size(4),
    agentMembers{ "Jacob", "Nathan", "Tomas", "Jack"} {
}
```

This version initialises the class variables with the given values, your version has two steps, first the class variables are *default initialised*, then you *assign* the given values to the variables. This is less efficient and there's no reason not to prefer the initialiser list version.

Comment: I did modify my above code to reflect your suggestion of agentMembers = { "Jacob", etc, however, it tells me there are too many initializer values (since the removal of the 4 of course).

Comment: @Robyn Unfortuneately I don't have a  compiler handy to check the code I've just written, so I might have made a mistake. This is also an area where C++ has changed recently, so it's possible that your compiler is not up to speed with the latest C++. You could always do it the old-fashioned way `agentMembers[0] = "Jacob"; agentMembers[1] = "Nathan"; agentMembers[2] = "Tomas"; agentMembers[3] = "Jack";`

Comment: Thank you and I appreciate the help, turns out that your very last suggestion as well as removing the int/string data-type fixed the issue. I had to manually enter the array names to the element.